# Agile - это зло? Или при каких условиях это выигрышный подход?

Tags: проектирование, agile, scrum, project-management

Один участник нашего *Стэк Оверфлоуа* в комментарии сказал такую фразу:

> По поводу ситуации когда требования доконца не ясны, это работа бизнес аналитика, он просто обязан подготовить ЧТЗ к которому не подкопаться, а эта работа занимает иногда даже несколько лет. В зависимости от масштаба проекта конечно. На протежении всей работы аналитика постоянно вносятся хотелки, в зависимости от погружения в процесс, вообщем эта работа довольно сложная, но на выходе качественная продукция. Ну и естественно ни каких еженедельных релизов, это самое большое зло которое выдумали на западе.

Заинтересовал этот вопрос.

С одной стороны, как мне кажется, раз подходы *Agile* или *SCRUM* практикуются, то значит им есть место быть. Слышал о примерах удачных исходов, тогда как до применения *Agile* были провалы, а с ними все отлично сложилось.

С другой стороны, действительно, задаешься вопросом, может ли такая переменчивость направления породить хороший продукт, который **годится** и со внутренней и с внешней стороны.

<strike>Понятно, что если речь идет о чем-то совсем не сложном по своему строению, то можно без проблем выкинуть какой-нибудь модуль и написать другой. Но если проект комплексный, сложный, со взаимосвязанными частями... Не получается ли так, что: сначала реализуются одни требования -> потом приходят новые -> ломается часть сделанного -> на этой уже кривой основе строится что-то новое -> и в итоге получается "крокодил"?</strike>

Еще, при Agile наверняка необходим "начальный капитал", то есть какой-то уже готовый фреймворк, в который остается только добавлять функционал. Так?

**Вопрос.** При каких условиях (тип проекта, окружающая среда ведения проекта, вовлеченные участники разработки, и т.д.) подход *Agile* имеет преимущества над классическими или другими подходами?

Интересны мнения людей с опытом участия в различных проектах.

---

**Update:**

Вытекающий/дополняющий вопрос: [Как реализовать подход *Agile* чтобы качество организации кода было приемлемым?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/539792/185885)

Answer (score 6):

Аджайл работает только если заказчик готов таким образом работать.

Плюсы в том, что он видит, что происходит и способен вмешаться/остановить, если поймёт, что делается вовсе не то, что ему надо. С одной стороны, такая разработка может потребовать больше времени из-за того, что требования меняются. Но с другой - заказчик-то в итоге получает именно то, что ему надо, а не то, что по его описанию подумал аналитик.

Но если заказчик так работать не готов, то лучше и не связываться.

Answer (score 5):

Во всех более-менее крупных разработках я только пару раз работал *не с Agile* (хотя, фактически этот термин нигде ни разу не применялся), когда заказчик выдавал действительно законченные ТЗ.

Один раз с Honeywell (FVS File Versioning System) -- требовалось сделать аналог DEC CMS (Code Management System) для работы в сети из разных компов (Ultrix, SunOS, NT, VAX/VMS).

И второй раз для Mentor Graphics нужно было сконвертировать форматы файлов с одних станков печатных плат для других.

Во всех остальные работах что-то  постоянно менялись (иногда сильно, вплоть до смены архитектуры управляющей машины комплекса, иногда слабо и в лучшую сторону -- выбросили поддержку Х.400 при разработке шлюза почты ЦБ РФ) в ходе работы с непосредственным заказчиком.